# Error: Please select a default endpoint

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

Going through a tutorial on Treehouse  trying to create an Alexa skill using Lambda and coming up with the following error

please select and endpoint what does this mean and how do i go about solving this problem ?

Comment: You have already created a Lambda function for your Alexa Skill?

Comment: i think so how would i know very new to this

Comment: I would have posted similar to the answer below. But more explanation...after you have your Lambda function you should be able to find the ARN code for it, something like `arn:aws:lambda...` then in the Alexa "configuration" tab you'll find Endpoint. Select "AWS Lambda ARN" then paste the ARN code in the input. Now your Skill has an Endpoint.

Comment: thank you , i will now test

Answer (score 1):

You have to create lambda function first of which you can provide the URL in alexa developer site.

To create lambda function refer below page.

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html

[image]

Comment: i have created a lambda function still having the same issues

Comment: In what region you created the lamba function? is it in N. Virginia?

Comment: Am also facing same problem. Region is N. Virginia